# Same fragment XML with different TAGs multiple times in Android within a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

the problem is that I am calling a Fragment class multiple times (everyone with a different argument), and then I need to recall afterwards this arguments to do some processing. But, whenever I call this argument when I need it, it is the same for every fragment, even though I explicitly called it with different arguments!

Here's some code to help you guys understand the problem.

NewStudentActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_student);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_new_student);

    UserDataFragment frag = new UserDataFragment();
    frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "user_data");

    measurementList = new SparseArray<>(4);

    //...

  private void setupViewPager (ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    if (calcMethod == Utility.PETROVSKI){
        if (userGender == Utility.GENDER_MALE){


            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_TRICIPITAL),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_TRICIPITAL);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_PANTURRILHA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_PANTURRILHA);

        } else if (userGender == Utility.GENDER_FEMALE) {
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_AXILAR),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_AXILAR);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_COXA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_COXA);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_PANTURRILHA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_PANTURRILHA);

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else if (calcMethod == Utility.GUEDES) {
        if (userGender == Utility.GENDER_MALE){
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_ABDOMINAL),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_ABDOMINAL);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA);

        } else if (userGender == Utility.GENDER_FEMALE) {
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_COXA_PROXIMAL),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_COXA_PROXIMAL);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUPRAILIACA);
            adapter.addFragment(MeasurementFragment.newInstance(Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR),
                    Utility.MEASUREMENT_SUBESCAPULAR);

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment (Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

MeasurementFragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_measurement, container, false);

    measurement1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.te_first_measurement);
    measurement2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.te_second_measurement);
    measurement3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.te_third_measurement);
    median = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mediana);
    median.setKeyListener(null);

    btn_check = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_check_measurements);

    btn_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            returnValues();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public static MeasurementFragment newInstance(String measurement){
    MeasurementFragment frag = new MeasurementFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    arg = measurement;

    args.putString(ARG_MEASUREMENT, measurement);

    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

private void returnValues(){
    if (checkMedian()){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        receiver = (MeasurementFinished) getActivity();

        data.putString("measurement", arg);
        data.putDouble("mediana", median_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement1", first_measurement_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement2", second_measurement_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement3", third_measurement_value);

        receiver.onMeasurementFinished(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your declaration of `arg` that shows up in `newInstance` and `returnValues`, but since you're using it in a static method it must be a static field.

That means there's only one per class, so when you say `arg = measurement` you're assigning different values to the same field over and over.  That's why you only ever see one value.

Try this:

```
public static MeasurementFragment newInstance(String measurement){
    MeasurementFragment frag = new MeasurementFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    // don't use the static arg here
    args.putString(ARG_MEASUREMENT, measurement);

    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

private void returnValues(){
    if (checkMedian()){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        receiver = (MeasurementFinished) getActivity();
        // this is how you get a value set with setArguments
        String measurement = getArguments().getString(ARG_MEASUREMENT);
        data.putString("measurement", measurement);
        data.putDouble("mediana", median_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement1", first_measurement_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement2", second_measurement_value);
        data.putDouble("measurement3", third_measurement_value);

        receiver.onMeasurementFinished(data);
    }
}
```